# WCF service with generic service class and contract?

Tags: c#, wcf, generics, web-config, app-config

Consider the following very simple code snippet that implements a web service that just echoes back any (string) object that the client sends to it:

```
namespace ServiceExample
{
    //------ Generic service and interface -----------
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IGenericService<T>
    {
        [OperationContract]
        T Echo(T subject);
    }

    public class GenericService<T>: IGenericService<T>
    {
        public T Echo(T subject)
        {
            return subject;
        }
    }

    //-- Non-generic variant where T is set to be a string --

    [ServiceContract]
    public interface INonGenericService : IGenericService<string>
    {}

    public class NonGenericService: GenericService<string>, INonGenericService
    {}
}
```

In app.config I can configure the service this way:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="ServiceExample.NonGenericService">

        <endpoint 
          address="http://localhost:1111/" 
          binding="basicHttpBinding" 
          contract="ServiceExample.INonGenericService" />

      </service>
    </services>
 </system.serviceModel>
```

This works great.

However, I am very annoyed by having to define those empty non-generic versions of the service class (and service contract) for the sole purpose of getting some valid non-generic names to put into the .config file.

Why can’t I just specify *directly* in the .config file, that I want the string-version of the generic class and interface? I imagine it could be done like this:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="ServiceExample.GenericService`1[[System.String]], mscorlib">

        <endpoint
          address="http://localhost:1111/"
          binding="basicHttpBinding"
          contract="ServiceExample.IGenericService`1[[System.String]], mscorlib" />

      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

I tried very hard, but so far with no success. Is this not possible at all?

Comment: FYI, that should be ``ServiceExample.GenericService`1[[System.String, mscorlib]]``, note that mscorlib is in the brackets.